# JPA/Hibernate + get specific item from onetomayrelation

Tags: java, collections, jpa, persistence

I want to get a specific row in a OneToMany relation. E.g. getting the cheapest item of an order

Example:

```
public class Order {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
 private Long id;

 ???
 private Item cheapestItem;

}

public class Item {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
 private Long id;

 private Long price;

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Item cheapestItem`? If you really want cheapest order, you should place that in the `Item` class

Comment: That's correct. I changed the example

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a where clause in the hibernate `@Where` annotation (Not sure if you can apply it to a non-collection, though)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get (...) the cheapest item of an order

If you really want to get the cheapest `Item` (without actually persisting it), it *should be* is doable with a `ManyToOne` and a `JoinColumnOrFormula`. Requires Hibernate 3.5+, see issues like [HHH-4382](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4382) and [HHH-5041](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5041) for examples.

Retrieving only the price would be much easier and doable with previous versions of Hibernate. See [Hibernate Derived Properties - Performance and Portability](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2009/07/hibernate-derived-properties.html).